# After project import Google Sign in and Google Maps location services not working

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I've had working project with Google Logins and Google Maps with GPS. After reinstalled my Windows, I newly imported my Android project and sadly I can't make it working now.When app was working, I used Android 6, now after updates I have Android 7.

I think these two errors are my problems:

```
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
```

Could you suggest how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Add this in your project level gradle.

Comment: Added but, still the same
Am geeting another one error :
`W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.crash not found.`

Comment: can you add the app level and project level gradle file in your question? also tell about in which device you run the app.

Answer (score 0):

Add google() in your project level build. Gradle file.
Eg.

```
allprojects{
repositories { jcenter() { google () } } }
```